# calculate all possible rowwise ratios in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame of genes as rows and samples as columns and would like to calculate all possible ratios between the rows. The new rowname should indicate the genes from which the ratio was calculated. Any tips how to start?

```
        sample1 sample2 sample3
gene1   2       23      323
gene2   23      53      56
gene3   565     55      13
```

out:

```
             sample1 sample2 sample3
gene1_gene2  2/23    23/53   323/56
gene1_gene3  2/565   23/55   323/13
gene2_gene3  23/565  53/55   56/13
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use `combn` from `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, combn(rownames(df1), 2, FUN = function(x) 
       apply(df1[x, ], 2, paste, collapse="/"), simplify = FALSE))
row.names(out) <- combn(rownames(df1), 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
out
#           sample1  sample2 sample3 
#gene1_gene2 "2/23"   "23/53" "323/56"
#gene1_gene3 "2/565"  "23/55" "323/13"
#gene2_gene3 "23/565" "53/55" "56/13"
```

---

If we need the actual values, just replace the `paste` with

```
out <- do.call(rbind, combn(rownames(df1), 2, FUN = function(x) 
   apply(df1[x, ], 2, FUN = function(x) x[1]/x[2]), simplify = FALSE))
row.names(out) <- combn(rownames(df1), 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
out
#                sample1   sample2   sample3
#gene1_gene2 0.086956522 0.4339623  5.767857
#gene1_gene3 0.003539823 0.4181818 24.846154
#gene2_gene3 0.040707965 0.9636364  4.307692
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample1 = c(2L, 23L, 565L), sample2 = c(23L, 53L, 
55L), sample3 = c(323L, 56L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("gene1", 
"gene2", "gene3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can well use the `outer` function. Something like the following, even if not very elegant:

```
library(magrittr) # just for the %>% pipe...
df <- data.frame(gene=c("G1", "G2", "G3"), s1=runif(3), s2=runif(3), s3=runif(3))

dfnew <- data.frame(comb=outer(df$gene, df$gene, paste, sep="_") %>% as.vector, s1ratio=outer(df$s1,df$s1, "/") %>% as.vector)

dfnew

   comb        s1
1 G1_G1 1.0000000
2 G2_G1 2.7052199
3 G3_G1 1.3417876
4 G1_G2 0.3696557
5 G2_G2 1.0000000
6 G3_G2 0.4959995
7 G1_G3 0.7452744
8 G2_G3 2.0161312
9 G3_G3 1.0000000
```